# Ambiguous Column Name/No Such Table Errors (SQLite)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm new at this but I'm trying to combine the columns in the `SELECT` statement from the `player_game_log` table and the `date` column in the `game` table, but I get `No such table as game.date` and when I remove the `.date.` then I get an error saying `ambiguous column name: game_id`. What am I getting wrong?

```
-- Jalen Green player_id = 1630224
SELECT player_id, game_id, pts, reb, ast
FROM player_game_log
INNER JOIN
    game.date
    ON
    player_game_log.game_id = game.game_id
WHERE player_id = 1630224
ORDER BY pts DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ambiguous column name: game_id` means that you have a `game_id` column in more than one of the tables you are JOINing, so when you say `SELECT game_id` the database doesn't know which one you want.

You need to specify which one you mean, like `SELECT game.game_id`.